# Spring boot and Android Retrofit 2.0 , file upload with json data

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, retrofit2

I have a REST API written using Spring boot and i am trying to POST an image and json data through Android client/app where i am using retrofit 2.0 . While doing that , i can see the data appearing but image file is showing as NULL.
can you please help me how to do this or let me know where i am doing the mistake

Server side REST Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/producttest", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody ProductTestResponse create( @Valid String producttestEntry,
    @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    LOGGER.info("Creating a product test: {}", producttestEntry);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> map;
    try {
        map = mapper.readValue(productbuyerEntry, Map.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Android Side code:

```
 MultipartBody.Part reqFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", finalFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), finalFile));
    Call <PostTestresponse> cal = restInterface.Posttest(hj, reqFile);
```

Comment: I too have same kind of problem